# How do you get the name of a UIImageView that you have set programmatically?

Tags: swift

I have programmatically defined a UIImageView as such:

```
  let imageConstant: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     image.image = UIImage(named: "imageNameSavedInAssets")
    return image
}()
```

How do I access the name of imageConstant's image?
That is, how can I access the name of imageConstant.image which reads "imageNameSavedInAssets"?

Comment: Why do you need it? This sounds like an XY problem. You should check your model, not your views.

Comment: This is just a homework assignment that I need to complete. Been reading up documentation and properties but I do not know how this is done.

Comment: I doubt the homework asked you to do _this specific task_ of getting the name of the image given this exact code. What did the homework ask you to do?

Comment: Nope, the code is mine, I am supposed to interpolate the name of the said image into a statement such that it reads: "You have chosen a \(nameOfTheImage)" which will actually read "You have chosen a banana"

Comment: You can achieve that in other ways. But I think there's no way to get the name of any UIImage, it's only used to get the file but not stored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIImageView - How to get the file name of the image assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom class to set and get the image name.

```
class customImageView: UIImageView {

var imageName: String?

func setImage(_ name: String) {
    imageName = name
    image = UIImage(named: imageName ?? "")!
}
```

}

accessibilityIdentifier is usually used in user accessibility(not suitable everywhere).

The most recommended way is to use Tag property of view. Depending on your tag change the image.

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image1"))
imageView.tag = 1
switch imageView.tag {
case 1:
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
imageView.tag = 2
case 2:
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
imageView.tag = 3
default:
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image3")
imageView.tag = 1
}
```

for more info, refer the thread :
[swift, How to get currently displayed image file name from UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515845/swift-how-to-get-currently-displayed-image-file-name-from-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIImageView and add a custom variable that will hold the name of the image file. Something like,

```
class customImageView: UIImageView {

var fileName: String?

  init(name: String?) {
    super.init()
    fileName = name
  }
}
```

Add whatever other initializers XCode requires.

```
let imageView = customImageView("banana")

print(imageView.fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

`accessibilityIdentifier` property of `UIImageView` correctly returns the input string you gave in its image instantiation, or nil if the string is not a valid name.